# How to generate apk without signing

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo

I have an app on google play made with expo, I really don't know much about APK key signing XD
Expo generated the key automatically and when I uploaded it on google play I used app signing by Google Play : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423
Now I'm using React Native without expo for the app, according to this documentation : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android to build a release version I need to generate the key signing, is it ok to do this and upload it to google play and everything will be the same? or is there a way to generate APK without signing since google play will do it for me?

Comment: I am not too sure with Expo. I can't recall if you have an android native source folder with Expo. If you do you can run "gradlew assembleRelease" in the android folder, or open the android folder in android studio and select assemble release. This will create an unsigned APK in the android build folder.

Comment: I was using expo but now I moved the work to React Native only, so yeah there is android folder, is it fine if I uploaded the APK without signing? I mean it's the same as before with Expo right? since the signing is handled by google play?

Comment: You still need a signed upload key. Refer to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing